# cfinput image type and cfwindow problem

Tags: coldfusion, cfform

I am looping over an image directory to list bunch of thumbnails. I want to show the original image on a click event. But for now, just a window.

```
      <cfform name="myform" format="flash" skin="haloorange">
         <cfinput type="image" src="../thumbs/#currentRow#" name="img#ListGetAt(qryImg.name,1,'.')#"<!--- onclick="javascript:ColdFusion.Window.show('mywindow4')">
       </cfform>
```

My problem is the onclick event. If I remove that piece of code, the form loads. IF I keep it, the form does not load. 
Also, I tried getURL(javascript:ColdFusion.Window.show('mywindow4')) but go no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got rid of cfwindow and ColdFusion.Window.show()

```
      onclick="getURL('javascript:show(5)')" >  

    <script>
    function show(u) {
      if(u != '') window.open('cfWinSource.cfm', 'sub', 'directories=no, location=no, menubar=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=no, status=no, titlebar=yes, toolbar=no, height=435, width=535')
    }
   </script>
```

seems to work for now.